# Function with try except in np.vectorize returns error message

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a, vectorized, function that does a simple adjustment on a number

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def adjust_number(number: int) -> int:

    max_number = 6
    default_substitue = 2

    # Try to convert to int, if not possible, use default_substitue
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except:
        number = default_substitue

    return min(number, max_number)
```

I apply the function on a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1.0, 9.0, np.nan]})
df = df.assign(adjusteded_number=lambda x: adjust_number(x['numbers']))
```

This returns the expected outputs, but I also get a strange return message

```
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2412: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in adjust_number (vectorized)
outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
```

It is not a huge issue, but it is very annoying. The error seems to be triggered by the `try-except`. If I modify the function, removing the `try-except`, which I really cannot do without breaking the functionality, the error goes away.

What is causing this and how can I get rid of the error message?

Comment: @AloneTogether that seems to work. Thanks. However, I would prefer to have the conversion inside the function. Clean code and all that...

Comment: Will the numbers always be integers (except for NaNs), but potentially held as floats? Or could they actually be floats, e.g., 4.4, which you want the function to convert to integers?

Comment: @AloneTogether the numbers will always be integers but potentially held as floats. I am using this function along with a number of other expressions that I am piping together. That is why I don't want to do an explicit conversion. The latter suggestion seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is NaN's/infinities that you are worried about, you use the NumPy [`isfinite`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) function to check for these:

```py
@np.vectorize
def adjust_number(number: int) -> int:
    max_number = 6
    default_substitue = 2

    # Try to convert to int, if not possible, use default_substitue
    if np.isfinite(number):
        number = int(number)
    else:
        number = default_substitue

    return min(number, max_number)
```

If you also want to make sure the the number was also actually an integer even if it's held as a float, you could do:

```py
@np.vectorize
def adjust_number(number: int) -> int:
    max_number = 6
    default_substitue = 2

    # Try to convert to int, if not possible, use default_substitue
    if np.isfinite(number):
        # make sure number is integer
        if isinstance(number, int) or (isinstance(number, float) and number.is_integer()):
            number = int(number)
        else:
            default_substitute
    else:
        number = default_substitue

    return min(number, max_number)
```

Alternatively, you don't even need to use `vectorize`, and could instead do:

```py
def adjust_number(number):
    default_substitute = 2
    max_number = 6
    num = np.asarray(number)  # make sure input is array
    num[~np.isfinite(num)] = default_substitute
    return np.clip(num, a_min=None, a_max=max_number).astype(int)
```

Comment: pandas has good `nan` testing.  Have you explored that?